# gradle exclude specific jars from runtime dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management

Is there a way to exclude specific jars from a group using Gradle?  I have tried below code, but this removed all the jars of that group

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'org.xxxx.xxxx'
}
```

My requirement is to remove only specific jars from the group, not all jars. This exercise we are doing to exclude transitive dependencies during runtime in our system.

thanks.

Comment: Use the `compileOnly` dependency set

Comment: For this specific issue, also specify the `module` map key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude all dependencies from a group, or only some modules of a group, in dependencies block:

```
    dependencies {

        /* --------------  SpringBoot without Tomcat  ------------------- */
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {    
            exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        }

    }
```

I add link to the Gradle documentation explaining transitive dependencies in detail: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html